# Opening a .txt file in Python and reading every character separately and storing it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and I need this for an exam.
I have two txt files that have a movie theater seating data in them.
I'm trying to open the file, read the seats that are taken and the ones that are free and want to store this information.

The txt looks a bit like this:

```
xxxxooxoxxx
xooxoxxoxox
ooxxxoxooxx
```

o-s are where the seat is free and x-s are taken.
so the first seat of the 2nd raw is taken but the 3rd and 4th are free.

I don't know how to properly store data or open a file character by character I guess. I'm really not sure how to start.

Comment: I am not sure why you think that you must read the file character by character in order to achieve your goal. Why not read the file line by line and then examine all the characters of each line?

Comment: I'm also not sure what exactly your question is, since you did not give us any concrete result/output for the sample txt file.

Comment: Could you define the question more clearly? Are you asking how to read a file? Or how to save the file? Or how to separate different values in a file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope, that I understood your question correctly. If your file is not extremely large (more than few 100 MB), then you can propably read whole file and store its content to a variable.

Let say, that this txt file is saved as `data.txt`. Then you can open a file with this two lines:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
```

Data is now list of lines.

```
>>> data
['xxxxooxoxxx\n', 'xooxoxxoxox\n', 'ooxxxoxooxx\n']
```

Now, I would convert data list to a 2d array of booleans. Here is an ugly one liner:

```
>>> taken = [[seat == 'x' for seat in row.rstrip()] for row in data]
```

Now you can determine if seat is taken or not like this:

```
>>> taken[1][1]
False
>>> taken[1][0]
True
```

Comment: Thanks, you're awesome.

The idea was a bit too complicated me but I watched a YT vid to understand what you were explaining here and now that I do it's exactly what I needed.
Thanks!

Comment: @BotondHorváth Don't forget to accept this answer if it solved your question. It'll mark this question as solved

Comment: @matejm You were using an ugly one liner there to quote you. Since I'm kinda new to this I wanted to understand and come up with something I can see through better and not just copy and paste.

onestring = foglaltsag.readline()
strings = foglaltsag.readlines()
allseats = "".join(strings)

rows = []
seats = []
char = 300

original = 0
n1 = 0
n2 = 0

while n2 != 20:
    while len(seats) != 15:
        seattype = allseats[n1]
        seats.append(seattype)
        n1 = n1 + len(onestring)
    n2 = n2 + 1
    n1 = original + 1
    original = original + 1

Answer (score 0):

To open a file in the same directory as the python file, use

```
file=open("file.txt","r")
file1=file.read()
```

This is how you open a file in read mode (the `r`). Now you want to have a list of characters, so you can use the list function.

```
file1=list(file1)
```

Now you get a list of all the characters. If you want to split it by newlines, instead of using list, use split.

```
file1=file1.split('\n')
```

And finally, close the file.

```
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

can read a file with **open** function in python with 'r' option:

```
with open("file.txt", 'r') as f:
    for row in f:
        for each_char in str(row):
            print each_char
            # Here use your statement
```